# "Не дожил" — падеж

Tags: грамотная-речь, падежи, управление

Поправил в [Википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9,_%D0%98%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%84_%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87) фразу:

> Иосиф Александрович Бродский скоропостижно скончался в ночь c 27 на 28 января 1996 года, не дожив 4 месяц**а** до своего 56-летия.

Поменял на *не дожив 4 месяц**ев**,* но мою правку отменили.

*Как правильно?* Посмотрел примеры в Нацкорпусе — до середины прошлого века преобладает явно ***родительный*** падеж!

По предложению Alex_ander нашёл две цитаты авторитетных авторов:

> ...Я и сегодня на панихиду приду, и еще приду; и... к тому же завтра ― день вашего рожденья, мама, милый друг мой! **Не дожил он трех дней только!** Я вышел в болезненном удивлении: как же это задавать такие вопросы ― приду я или нет на отпевание в церковь? *[Ф. М. Достоевский. Подросток (1875)]*
>
> Умерла, **не дожив дня** до выхода журнала с очерком о погибшем в начале войны сыне, Наталия Николаевна Антокольская, прекрасная русская женщина. *[Ю. М. Нагибин. Дневник (1983)]*

Comment: *Что в лоб, что по лбу* — это ваш ответ?))

Comment: _Артём Луговой: "Что в лоб, что по лбу — это ваш ответ?"_  === Да.

Comment: @slava1947: получается, у меня нет оснований поменять на родительный?

Comment: _Артём Луговой: "получается, у меня нет оснований поменять на родительный?"_  === Я таких оснований не вижу.

Comment: Артём, в корпусной коллекции на этот запрос встречаются классики? Я просмотрел первые страницы (их много, и не хватило терпения на все) - не попалось безусловно авторитетных авторов.

Comment: Вроде не попалось, Александр. Но я ещё посмотрю получше, надеюсь, у меня хватит терпения. :)

Comment: @Alex_ander: добавил примеры в ответ.

Comment: @Артем, после числительных 1, 2, 3, 4 существильное ставится в ед. ч родительного падежа.

Comment: @Серж: не понял вас... Про единицу особенно. Мне, кстати, так не приходят уведомления.

Comment: @Артем,если я вас правильно понял, вы исправили ед. на мн. ч. после цифры. Верно? Но вашу правку отменили.

Comment: Когда вы пишете @Артём, Серж, мне не приходят уведомления обычно. Всё правильно. Я исправил винительный падеж на родительный. А единственное или множественное — это уже вторично. Если числительное "четырёх" ставится в родительный падеж, то "дней" после него в любом случае получается во множественном числе.

Comment: Подождите.Месяца - ведь не винительный падеж.  Странно, что вам не приходят уведомления.

Comment: Они приходят, когда написаны имя с фамилией вместе без пробелов (и у меня именно с Ё). В этой цепочке уже стали приходить и так. Да, простите, наверное это именительный падеж. Не "месяца", а вместе — "четыре месяца".

Comment: 4 (чего?) месяца. Родительный падеж. Почему вы все словосочетание считаете именительным падежом?

Comment: Я не знаю, правильно так или нет, но давайте рассмотрим первое слово. Оно либо в родительном, либо в именительном падеже. А второе слово уже под него подстраивается непременно в родительном, только в разных числах.

Comment: А почему неправильно? Четыре - именительный падеж.

Comment: Вопрос был в том, говорить "четыре" или "четырёх".

Comment: Артём, как видно из словарной статьи, здесь корректнее употребить предлог до. Не дожил до. Тогда правильно: не дожил четырех месяцев.

Comment: ДОЖИТЬ, -живу, -живёшь; дожил, -ла, -ло; дожитый; -жит, -а, -о; св. 1. Достичь какого-л. возраста; прожить до какого-л. срока, события. Д. до возвращения сына. Д. до двадцати лет. Д. до старости. Д. до седых волос (до старости). 2. Разг. Провести остаток времени где-л. Дожил лето на даче

Comment: Так в моём примере и есть "до": *до своего 56-летия.*

Comment: Да, но у вас предлог до стоит после числительного. Поэтому я все же за именительный падеж.  Не дожил (сколько?) четыре месяца. А не (скольких?)четырех месяцев.

Comment: А мне больше родительный нравится. Хоть даже, как отметил Александр, отрицания тут явного нет.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вообще-то если трактовать конструкцию как падеж при отрицании, то нужен именно родительный. Видимо, в прошлые времена, о которых вы упоминаете, так и поступали. 
Если вспомнить всю проблему "винительный vs родительный при отрицании", то винительный используется только в некоторых ситуациях, чаще всего для указания конкретности: "не пей воды" - вообще (доктор запретил), "не пей воду" - эту вот (грязную). А какая тут конкретность, если речь идет просто о времени?
Поэтому "не дожив недели, месяца" смотрится явно лучше варианта "неделю, месяц".

Вариативность, видимо, возникает в силу употребления сочетания с количественным числительным. Такие сочетания как бы стремятся восстановить винительный при отрицании. Почему это происходит - мне непонятно, но тенденция налицо.

> получается, у меня нет оснований поменять на родительный?

Нет императивных оснований. И так и эдак можно. Но по мне - родительный все-таки лучше.

Comment: Спасибо! Рад, что вы тоже склоняетесь больше в сторону родительного. Ладно, придётся проглотить пилюлю (оставить так).

Comment: _Артём Луговой: "Ладно, придётся проглотить пилюлю (оставить так)"_. === А может, не только в падеже дело? Правку Вашу могли отменить и из-за Вашей невнимательности! В источнике было (по Вашим словам) — "**не дожив**", Вы же предложили — "**не дожил**", что плохо сочеталось с предыдущей частью предложения.

Comment: Нет-нет, деепричастия я не менял, лишь в вопросе по невнимательности изменил слово.

Answer (score 2):

Посмотрим, почему с родительным падежом явно лучше звучит *похожее* выражение:

> Не **прожив** 4 месяцев (= прожив *менее* 4 месяцев) после ранения, он
>   закончил свой путь.

Это стилистически правильный вариант - в ином случае (винительный падеж) возникает вопрос: почему именно 4 месяца "не прожил"? Он что, планировал такой срок? Отрицание акцентирует здесь количество (не было и 4), а не факт прожития (он "прожил", но меньше названного срока).

В нашем же случае количественная оценка нейтральна (*сколько именно* месяцев "**он не дожил**" до некой даты). Отрицательная частица здесь не направлена на уточнение, больше это или меньше приводимой цифры, она просто указывает на тот факт, что "он не дожил" до этого дня. Однако внешняя похожесть на случай "**не прожил и стольких-то**" порождает относительно большой процент случаев родительного падежа в коллекции "корпуса" (там преимущественно журнальные статьи от журналистов). Насколько это уместно? Представим себе такой диалог:

- Он не дожил до своего 60-летия.
- И сколько не дожил?
- Четыре месяца.

Риторический вопрос: что может заставить здесь перейти к родительному падежу при переходе от диалога к косвенной речи?

Более очевидным вопрос о падеже становится в случае прямого указания на точность (или, наоборот, приблизительность) приводимой цифры: стоит добавить к ней "**ровно (4 месяца)**" или даже "**примерно**", и *невозможность* родительного падежа становится явной.

> ...**не дожив** (ровно/примерно) 4 месяца до своего 56-летия.

А так ли велика разница, *подразумевается* точный (приблизительный) срок (у нас могло и совпасть по числам, что общего смысла не меняет) или *указывается явно*?

По этим причинам, на мой взгляд, в нашем примере изменение падежа на *родительный* вряд ли улучшило бы текст.

Comment: Спасибо, Александр!

Comment: Вот с "около" будет родительный: http://processing.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&mydocsize=&mode=main&sort=i_grtagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&text=lexgramm&parent1=0&level1=0&lex1=%D0%BD%D0%B5&gramm1=&sem1=&flags1=&sem-mod1=sem&sem-mod1=sem2&parent2=0&level2=0&min2=1&max2=1&lex2=%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C&gramm2=&sem2=&flags2=&sem-mod2=sem&sem-mod2=sem2&parent3=0&level3=0&min3=1&max3=3&lex3=%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE&gramm3=&sem3=&flags3=&sem-mod3=sem&sem-mod3=sem2. Почему бы и с *ровно/примерно* ему не появиться?

Comment: Около - _предлог_ этого падежа.

Comment: Еще можно "порядка" пристроить :) В примерах из классиков подчеркивается малось сроков (оставалось дожить до желаного события всего ничего), а у нас просто обозначено сколько до конкретного срока (56 лет - далеко не юбилей).

Comment: Согласен насчёт последнего комментария, что разница есть. Вот только всё равно остаётся мысль, что, несмотря на неё, родительный хорош просто из-за отрицания. Но что не единственно хорош, вы меня отчасти убедили. Жалко, что у самых классиков нету таких прицельных примеров на этот контекст. Что предлог этого падежа он, я понимаю, просто рассуждал, что если его можно употребить, то почему бы и не употребить другой предлог, пускай и не чисто родительного падежа.

Comment: Ага, "порядка" тоже искал в Нацкорпусе. ;)